# how to pass argument to the C program in the gdb mode of emacs

Tags: c, emacs, gdb

I used the gdb mode in emacs to run a small code counting the number of digits in a string, but when I type in the string (using the keyboard), the gdb did nothing but wait forever after I hit the "enter" button. I also tried gdb with Unix prompt directly and everything went smoothly. So is there any trick in passing the argument into the program in the gdb mode of emacs？

Comment: Are you referring to command-line arguments or arguments read from the standard input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to pass arguments to the debugged program is to add them after `gdb`'s run command.

For example:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`gdb`<kbd>RET</kbd>`echo`<kbd>RET</kbd>

```
Current directory is ~/
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3-debian
[...]
Reading symbols from /bin/echo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run foo
Starting program: /bin/echo foo
foo
[Inferior 1 (process 10176) exited normally]
```